# Scheme program parameters

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm creating a function

```
 (define (run program-string . arguments)
      (if (string? program-string)
          (value-of (create-ast program-string) (empty-env))
          (raise (string-append "expected a program as string, got: " (~a program-string)))
          )  
      )
```

Where "arguments" will be a string of arguments **or** an empty list '() that represent the program parameters. Each parameter in "arguments" will be binded, by position, to a variable in program-string, namely argN where N is the position of the specific parameter (beginning at 0).

```
Eg.

    (run "move((0 0) arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6)"
              "up(3)"
              "right(5)"
              "right(4)"
              "down(2)"
              "up(6)"
              "right(2)"
              "right(3)"
              )
Output: (coordinate-value '(point xcord ycord)) //
```

So, assume that all of those functions and values are already defined in my language, and that xcord and ycord are the actual coordinates after the final move.  Given that input, I want to bind "up(3)" to (0 0), "right(5)" to arg0.... etc, given any arbitrary amount of argN's and a corresponding amount of inputs for each of the args.

The run function basically needs to assign each arg its corresponding argument and run that final string.

Comment: are you trying to say that `if arguments are list, do this, and if string do this` or are you saying that you don't know how to specify (syntactically speaking) arguments within the definition, like so: `(define (foo bar) (display (string-append bar " is an arg!!"))`?
 **NOTE:** you might want to consider revising your question as it is rather hard to understand what you're trying to do; try adding the desired code usage and expected output, or something... I dunno, but I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for help on.

Comment: I'm also very confused by your question. When you say "arguments will be a string of arguments or an empty list '()", you can't have it both ways. As declared, `arguments` will be `list`, not a `string`. It could be a `list` of `string`s, but it's important to get clear what you want.

Comment: I've edited it, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to prepare an answer that's suitable for the question.

I'm going to assume that all the stuff like `up(3)` was really supposed to be s-expressions like `(up 3)`.  If not, too bad.

You didn't say what the desired output of your example was. I'm going to hope my math is OK and stipulate that it's position (14 -7).

The problem seemed to assume that only programs starting with `(move (0 0) ...)` are legal. I seized that assumption; I ain't letting go.

With that prelude, I present my interpretation of the homework exercise:

**The Horrible Little Love Child of `printf` and `eval`**.

```
#lang racket

;; the current position and functions to move it
(struct pos (x y) #:transparent)
(define the-pos (make-parameter (pos 0 0)))

(define (dx f n)
  (match (the-pos)
    [(pos x y) (the-pos (pos (f x n) y))]))
(define (dy f n)
  (match (the-pos)
    [(pos x y) (the-pos (pos x (f y n)))]))

(define (left n)  (dx - n))
(define (right n) (dx + n))
(define (up n)    (dy - n))
(define (down n)  (dy + n))

;; namespace for `eval`
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

;; start holding your nose
(define (run str . args)
  (define as (for/list ([a args])
               (read (open-input-string a))))
    (match (read (open-input-string str))
      [`(move (0 0) ,xs ...)
       (for ([x xs])
         (define n (match (symbol->string x)
                     [(pregexp "^arg(\\d)$" (list _ n)) (string->number n)]
                     [else (error 'run "bad argN")]))
         (unless (< -1 n (length as))
           (error 'run "bad argN"))
         (eval (list-ref as n) ns))
       (eval '(the-pos) ns)]))

;; a unit test to confirm our true evi^Hal
(require rackunit)
(the-pos (pos 0 0))
(check-equal?
 (run "(move (0 0) arg0 arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5 arg6)"
      "(up 3)"
      "(right 5)"
      "(right 4)"
      "(down 2)"
      "(up 6)"
      "(right 2)"
      "(right 3)")
 (pos 14 -7))

;; and since we went through all the argN nonsense, the reverse:
(the-pos (pos 0 0))
(check-equal?
 (run "(move (0 0) arg6 arg5 arg4 arg3 arg2 arg1 arg0)"
      "(right 3)"
      "(right 2)"
      "(up 6)"
      "(down 2)"
      "(right 4)"
      "(right 5)"
      "(up 3)")
 (pos 14 -7))
;; not that it matters with addition and subtraction...why am I even...
```